# How i can login in Gmail with Python?

Tags: python, authentication

The idea of ​​my code is to send a message to the mail ( x ) from the mail that I go to using the Login in the code. 17 line causes an error.

```
#main.py
import config as cfg
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

msg = MIMEMultipart()
to_email = 'dasdladalffhalf'

msg['Subject'] = input('Topic: ')
msg['From'] = cfg.LOGIN

msg_body = input('Text: ')
msg.attach(MIMEText(msg_body, 'plain'))


server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com: 587')
server.login(cfg.LOGIN, cfg.PASSWORD)
server.sendmail(cfg.LOGIN, to_email, msg.as_string())
```

```
#config.py
LOGIN = 'login'
PASSWORD = "password"
```

Comment: What error? Do you have 2FA turned on?

Comment: I tried turning 2FA on and off and nothing changed. This does not work.

Comment: The port number does not go into the hostname.  use SMTP_SSL(‘smtp.gmail.com’, 587)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to enable less secure apps in GMail for this to work. https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Sometimes you may also have to complete a captcha while logged into GMail - https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

More info: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en